# Prevent mutableSet order change in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

I am using a Mutable set of Strings to store some data whose order I dont want to change, by using preferenceEditObject.putStringSet() method. Although I add and remove data from the set, but the order should remain the same.

```
private fun getStrings(): MutableSet<String>? {
        return preferenceObject.getStringSet("initList", mutableSetOf())
    }
```

```
    private fun setStrings(list: MutableSet<String>?) {
        preferenceEditObject.putStringSet("initList",list).apply()
    }
```

But when I use the getStrings() method, the order of elements gets changed. What should I do?

Comment: If the order is significant, it's worth checking whether you actually need a List rather than a Set…

Comment: @gidds But can I save list using putStringSet method of shared preferences?

Comment: I don't know the API you're referring to — a web search suggests that that's an Android question, which I can't help you with. (Kotlin gets used for many different platforms: web apps, microservices, desktop apps, Android apps, iOS apps, and much more; I only know a few of those.)

Comment: Yes, I am using Kotlin for Android. And from some answers I looked at on SO, all of them were using a HashSet only, and the API's name itself expects a set, so I used a MutableSet. Thanks for the comment though. I didn't know Kotlin was so extensively used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing, store the index together with the value, and when reading, sort by this index

```
private fun getStrings(): Set<String> {
    return preferenceObject.getStringSet("initList", setOf())!!
        .map { it.split(":", limit = 2).let { (index, value) -> index.toInt() to value } }
        .sortedBy { it.first }
        .mapTo(mutableSetOf()) { it.second }
}

private fun setStrings(list: Set<String>) {
    preferenceEditObject.putStringSet("initList", list.mapIndexedTo(mutableSetOf()) { index, s -> "$index:$s" }).apply()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Quite a better approach. I wonder though why is not ordered by default. The docs say that it's always ordered.

Comment: @coderGtm `mutableSetOf()` uses `LinkedHashSet`, so it preserves order, but `SharedPreferences` internally uses regular `HashSet` which doesn't preserve order

Comment: Ohk!! Got it...